# Morph curve into line?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, vertices, fcurves, curve-modifier

I have a Curve object that has a complex shape and is very curved. The vertices are all lined up one after another. Is there a way I can force those vertices into a straight line with an arbitrary distance between them?

Ideally, this could be perhaps saved as a Shape Key or similar so I can animate between the original curve and the straight version. Maybe there's also a way to do this using GeoNodes?

Comment: yes shapekeys are a solution, have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a *curve line*, move the endpoints to position it (*set position* node with *endpoint selection* node plugged into the *selection* socket), resample it (*resample curve*) using the same number of points as your other curve, and then all you have to do is transfer the point positions between the two (*sample index* in *vector* mode with *position* plugged into the vector socket) and use the output in a *set position* node.

Comment: Sometimes an one image is more than a thousands words ... :)

Comment: @vklidu I think you meant to say: sometimes [A picture is worth a thousand words.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words). But interestingly *The phrase has been spoofed by computer scientist John McCarthy, to make the opposite point: "As the Chinese say, 1001 words is worth more than a picture."*

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yes I do :) I don't think it is a place to go deeper here, but I'm definetelly from visual generation :)

Answer (score 3):

[image]
[image]

Sorry I just couldn't get the result from Hadriscus's answer ... so here is what worked for me. For Blender 3.4+ use *Sample Index* node (instead of my Transfer Attribute).

To animate transition (morph) change *Factor* of *Mix* node (0-1).